# ImportError: No module named 'resource'

Tags: python, python-3.x, resources

I am using python 3.5 and I am doing Algorithms specialization courses on Coursera. Professor teaching this course posted a program which can help us to know the time and memory associated with running a program. It has `import resource` command at the top. I tried to run this program along with the programs I have written in python and every time I received `ImportError: No module named 'resource'`

I used the same code in ubuntu and have no errors at all.

I followed suggestions in stackoverflow answers and I have tried adding PYTHONPATH PYTHONHOME and edited the PATH environment variable.

I have no idea of what else I can do here.

Is there any file that I can download and install it in the Lib or site-packages folder of  my python installation ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`resource` is a Unix specific package as seen in https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html which is why it worked for you in Ubuntu, but raised an error when trying to use it in Windows.

Comment: One thing that might improve this answer is what alternate functionality to use on Windows, or if spinning up a Linux VM is the only option.

Comment: The module [psutil](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) provides a cross-platform library for monitoring and managing running processes and system usage (CPU, memory, disks, network, sensors).

Comment: So how can fix this bug? Any suggestion

Comment: make pip uninstall ipython  then pip install ipython

Answer (score 6):

I ran into similar error in window 10. Here is what solved it for me.

1. Downgrade to the Apache Spark 2.3.2 prebuild version
2. Install (or downgrade) jdk to version 1.8.0

   - My installed jdk was 1.9.0, which doesn't seem to be compatiable with spark 2.3.2 or 2.4.0
3. make sure that when you run java -version in cmd (command prompt), it show java version 8. If you are seeing version 9, you will need to change your system ENV PATH to ensure it points to java version 8.
4. Check this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/262757/changing-current-version-of-java-within-windows) to get help on changing the PATH if you have multiple java version installed.

Hope this helps someone, I was stuck on this issue for almost a week before finally finding a solution.

Comment: Works for me, too. I read that this is an Spark 2.4.0 issue and should be fixed in a future version.