# how to import resource module?

Tags: python

Today I see a python file starting with

```
import sys
import time
import heapq
import resource
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict
```

however, after I run the file, the error showed with

```
ImportError: No module named resource
```

then I try to install resource with pip install but cannot find such packages.

Any idea could be helpful!

Comment: try pip install python-resources

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named 'resource'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710848/importerror-no-module-named-resource)

Comment: `resource` is built in on UNIX systems. You are probably on windows, where it is not available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
pip install python-resources
```

or download the package form [**here**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-resources/0.3) and then install from the downloaded file

```
pip install python-resources-0.3.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Issue , but reading official[github repo] helps to resolve it on windows 10,

try replace `import resource`  to `import rsrc`

since the original name is conflict with the built-in library resource:

Answer (score 1):

To suppress the pylint import error (Windows), add the following pylint hint. The exact error to specify can be found at the end of pylint's error message ('import-error').

```
 if os.name == 'posix':
     import resource # pylint: disable=import-error
```