# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, python-3.6, modulenotfounderror

I am using Python 3.6 in anaconda on Windows 10.

I have tried to install the  `resource` package using `pip install resource`.

It says Requirements already satisfied. But still `import resource` showing the same error.

How to resolve this issue on Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49232580/how-to-import-resource-module

Comment: The solutions posted on this link does not work. Any other possible solutions?

Comment: According to its documentation, `resource` can only be used in Unix. Consider using [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) library which is a cross-platform library.