# Spark Release 2.4.0 can not work on win7 because of ImportError: No module named 'resource'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I  attempt to install Spark Release 2.4.0 on my pc, which system is win7_x64.

However when I try to run simple code to check whether spark is ready to work:
code:

```
import os
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local[*]').setAppName('word_count')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
d = ['a b c d', 'b c d e', 'c d e f']
d_rdd = sc.parallelize(d)
rdd_res = d_rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
print(rdd_res)
print(rdd_res.collect())
```

I get this error:

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzlXQ.png)

I open the worker.py file to check the code.

I find that, in version 2.4.0, the code is :

[worker.py  v2.4.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSULb.png)

However, in version 2.3.2, the code is:

[worker.py v2.3.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUYWW.png)

Then I reinstall spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7 , the code works fine.

Also, I find this question:
[ImportError: No module named 'resource'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710848/importerror-no-module-named-resource)

So, I think spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7  can not work in win7 because of importing 
resource module in worker.py, which is a Unix specific package.

I hope someone could fix this problem in spark.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Jason. Please [don't post exceptions as images](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). Could [edit] your question and include these as text? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i got this error and I have spark 2.4.0, jdk 11 and kafka 2.11 on windows.
I was able to resolve this by doing - 
  1) cd spark_home\python\lib 
   
ex. cd C:\myprograms\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python
  
2) unzip pyspark.zip 
  
3) edit worker.py , comment out 'import resource' and also following para and save the file. This para is just an add on and is not a core code, so its fine to comment it out.
  
4)remove the older pyspark.zip and create new zip. 
  
5) in jupyter notebook restart the kernel.

commented para in worker.py -

```
    # set up memory limits
    #memory_limit_mb = int(os.environ.get('PYSPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY_MB', "-1"))
    #total_memory = resource.RLIMIT_AS
    #try:
    #   if memory_limit_mb > 0:
            #(soft_limit, hard_limit) = resource.getrlimit(total_memory)
            #msg = "Current mem limits: {0} of max {1}\n".format(soft_limit, hard_limit)
            #print(msg, file=sys.stderr)

            # convert to bytes
            #new_limit = memory_limit_mb * 1024 * 1024

            #if soft_limit == resource.RLIM_INFINITY or new_limit < soft_limit:
            #    msg = "Setting mem limits to {0} of max {1}\n".format(new_limit, new_limit)
            #    print(msg, file=sys.stderr)
            #    resource.setrlimit(total_memory, (new_limit, new_limit))

    #except (resource.error, OSError, ValueError) as e:
    #    # not all systems support resource limits, so warn instead of failing
    #    print("WARN: Failed to set memory limit: {0}\n".format(e), file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has some compatibility issue with the newly released Spark 2.4.0 version. I also faced this similar issue. If you download and configure Spark 2.3.2 in your system (change environment variables), the problem will be resolved.