# How to use the python package resource in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, resources

I try to import resource but an error is raised that no module named resource. However, I have install this package by pip. How to fix this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsFuU.png)

Try to import resource.
Hope to know how to fix the error in Windows.

Comment: share the complete code so we may know where the preblem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'resource'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710848/importerror-no-module-named-resource)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `pip install resource` to see where the package is installed, you will get results similar to below:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2,>=0.14.0 in /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jsonschema->JsonForm>=0.0.2->resource) (0.18.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jsonschema->JsonForm>=0.0.2->resource) (21.4.0)
```

Then, check if the installed path (for me: /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages) is added to windows environment variables

Comment: I install other package in this way (pip install xxx) too. But this problem never happened before. I have tried your solution but it does not work.

Comment: update: `resource` is a unix specified lib, maybe you shoule use `psutil`, see in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710848/importerror-no-module-named-resource